# Make a page redirect when a number is 15 using if statements

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a piece of code redirect the user to a certain website after 15 is reached by a number. I would use the code below and it would not redirect even if the number is met.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="text">please wait <span id="thing" style="font-size: 70px;">0</span> seconds<span id="wait"></span></h1>
    <script>
        var request = document.getElementById("thing");
        var num = 0;
        var goup = setInterval(function goUp() {
            num++;
            request.innerHTML = num;
        }, 1000)
        var dots = window.setInterval(function dots() {
            var waiter = document.getElementById("wait");
            if (waiter.innerHTML.length > 5) {
                waiter.innerHTML = ""
            } else {
                waiter.innerHTML += ".";
            }
        }, 100)
        if (num.innerHTML === 15) {
            location.href('https://google.com/');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` returns a string so it can never `===` a number. `===` only matches when type and value are the same

Comment: Also `if (num.innerHTML === 15)` only runs once after the page has loaded.

Comment: `num` is a variable, not an element, so it does not have the property of `innerHTML`. The value of the timer is the value of `num` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="text">please wait <span id="thing" style="font-size: 70px;">15</span> seconds<span id="wait"></span></h1>
  <script>
    var request = document.getElementById("thing");
    var num = 15;
    var goup = setInterval(function goUp() {
      request.innerHTML = --num;
      if (num === 0) {
        window.location.href = 'https://google.com/';
      }
    }, 1000)
    var dots = window.setInterval(function dots() {
      var waiter = document.getElementById("wait");
      if (waiter.innerHTML.length > 5) {
        waiter.innerHTML = ""
      } else {
        waiter.innerHTML += ".";
      }
    }, 100)
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I simply put the if statement inside the interval so it checks every time the 'timer' is updated. Also, I made the timer go backwards because you are telling the user to wait for 15 seconds, so it should be counting down. In addition, I changed `location.href()` to `window.location.href =`, since `location.href()` isn't a function, it's a string, so you need to change it using an assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var request = document.getElementById("thing");
    var num = 0;
    var goup = setInterval(function goUp() {
      request.innerHTML = num++;
      if (num === 4) {
        clearInterval(goup)
        location.href = 'https://google.com/';
      }
    }, 1000)
    var dots = window.setInterval(function dots() {
      var waiter = document.getElementById("wait");
      if (waiter.innerHTML.length > 5) {
        waiter.innerHTML = ""
      } else {
        waiter.innerHTML += ".";
      }

    }, 100)
```